# What is Yue's relationship with Toya?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

In Cardcaptor Sakura, Yukito and Toya are romantically involved, or at least shown to have romantic feelings for each other. Yukito tells Sakura of his love for Toya. Has it ever been expressed or officially announced what Yue, Yukito's alter-ego, feels towards Toya?

Comment: Wait, what? When did I miss that part? They were romantically involved?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Read the relationships part of http://ccs.wikia.com/wiki/Yukito_Tsukishiro. It shows up a lot, especially in the episode where Yukito is dying because Sakura didn't have enough power to sustain him. Toya gave up all of his magic to save Yukito (ep 65).

Comment: I know of that one, but not that they were *romantically involved*. That one was news to me

Comment: Yukito clearly likes Toya in a romantic sense in the series, but can you give any example (manga chapter or anime episode) in which Toya expressed any clear romantic feelings toward Yukito? Even if Toya is not averse to Yukito's feelings and has affection for him, I cannot recall any moment from which they became an established couple (i.e. became "romantically involved").

Answer (score 4):

As you have said, Toya and Yukito has romantic feelings for each other. As for Yue, it can be implied that he has no romantic feelings for Toya (since he knew ever since everything about Yukito, he probably had known that Yukito has feelings for Toya and wouldn't interfere). And according [here](http://ccs.wikia.com/wiki/Yue),

> **Yue was in quite a strong and close intimate relationship with Clow
>   Reed.**

Yue was even against Sakura, as he strongly believed that no one succeed Clow Reed, but later on accepted her as his new master. So if there's somebody who Yue has romantic feelings for, it probably would be Clow Reed.

In addition, as far as I can remember, the only specific event that Yue and Toya had a conversation was when Toya gave his power to Yue and made Yue promise to protect Sakura and Yukito.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Yue is cold toward Sakura. He is a very nostalgic person who only recognize Clow Reed. 
But Sakura's warmth melted the coldness in his heart, and he recognized Sakura as his new mistress deep within his heart. He and Sakura gets quite intimate in the battles to turn Clow Cards into Sakura cards, and even wiped her tears away in Episode 65 when Sakura overheard the conversation and transfer of powers between Yue and Toya.
Does Yukito and Toya have romantic feelings for each other? I'd say yes.
But how about Yue's feeling for him? Truthfully, I think after such a long time with Sakura, he has stronger emotional attachment to her than to Toya, whom he met only once in his true form. It is his false form, Yukito, who had feelings for Toya.

Answer (score -2):

I always thought that if, in the manga they make it clear to a certain point with Yukito; With Yue believed that if he has feelings for Toya even if it is false appearance he did not believe that they can only "create" those feelings unconsciously and he feels it. In the end they are the same person, two sides of the same coin.

Comment: I've translated this to English, but since I don't know Spanish I've had to use Google Translate which isn't always great. If anyone would like to propose a more accurate translation that'd be great.